# Pandas data frame change float values when read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Hi I have a situation in hand ,

I have an excel whose one column contains the following :

```
    DOUBLE_FI_EXC_RETURN
      0.21
     -0.52
     -0.28
     -0.01
      0.45
      0.24
     -1.12
     -0.14
```

Now when i do df.read_excel() it returns this data frame:

```
DOUBLE_FI_EXC_RETURN
 0.214307422
-0.517325534
-0.28279697
-0.005493749
 0.452745819
 0.238851397
-1.116148896
-0.141628643
```

I think it is giving me an accurate value but i need the same values from excel . How should i get them

Comment: By `accurate value` I think it's giving you the exact value that is stored in the cell. Most likely, you have some formatting option specified in excel to only display 2 decimal places, though the cell contains the precise value. If it's for display, then fine, format away. But if you are doing calculations, you likely don't want to round, as the error will propagate through your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to round the values after 2 precisions if you really want to. Excel might be showing you values that are rounded but `pandas` might be capturing the exact values with correct precision. If you really want to round the values you can do so by:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'DOUBLE_FI_EXC_RETURN':[0.214307422,
                                         -0.517325534,
                                         -0.28279697,
                                         -0.005493749,
                                          0.452745819,
                                          0.238851397,
                                         -1.116148896,
                                         -0.141628643,]})
df.DOUBLE_FI_EXC_RETURN.apply(lambda x:round(x,2))
```

Or using numpy

```
np.round(df.DOUBLE_FI_EXC_RETURN, 2)
```

Comment: oh i noticed it was actually a excel formatting done actual values are same thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use `round` if you want to reduce the precision

```
round(DOUBLE_FI_EXC_RETURN, 2)
```

Comment: This will give `DOUBLE_FI_EXC_RETURN` not defined

Comment: It worked for me, but your solutions are likely much more efficient